# Calcuate the test statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

I am facing a little problem is this question. Can somebody please help e here

A sample of 500 drivers was asked whether or not they speed while driving. The following table gives a two-way classification:

[image]

We wish to test whether gender and speeding are related at the 1% significant level.

What is the critical value for the test? Also state the null and alternative hypothesis and test statistics for it. I need help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this problem you need to calculate the Chi-Square test of independence. Its not horribly complicated, and its well detailed in the Wikipedia article [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test). After that, the number you get should be compared to the ${X^2}_{0.010}$ column in [This](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~mga/401/tables/Chi-square-table.pdf) table of numbers. Now that you know the method, it should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Sir can u please help me out with the starting I mean some formula. Also is the null and alternative hypothesis be like this? H0 :p male =p female...  
 
Ha :p male <p female

Comment: For a chi square test of independence, your $H_0:$ There is no difference in the rates for each category aka they are independent $H_a:$ There is a difference in the rates for each category, aka, they are not independent

Comment: You are not testing one category against another, but all categories independence at once.